# Swift - AWSTaskCompletionSource example

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-sdk

According to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html), I can use `AWSTaskCompletionSource` to get `identity` and `token` asynchronously, but I can't seem to find any example about it.

Could you please show me some example that I can start to set `identityId` and `token` asynchronously?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

it's a late answer but maybe someone might still be looking for how to use it, here is a sample

```swift
//inside the token function or any other function create a completion object
let completionSource = AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSString>()
        
        //then call your backend to fetch the token and identityId
        self.idCancellable = GetAWSDevOpenId().call().sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in}) { [weak self , completionSource] (credentials : [String]?) in
            if let cred = credentials , let self = self, cred.count > 1 {
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Id successfully fetched: \(cred)")

                //then update the token and identityId
                self.identityId = cred.first
                completionSource.set(result: cred[1] as NSString)
            } else {
                print(">>>>>> something went wrong")
                completionSource.set(error: NSError())
            }
        }
        
        //return the task
        return completionSource.task
```